# How to update partials

Tags: ractivejs

Hi there RactiveJS users, I'm new here and I'm very excited using RactiveJS but, I came up to wonder if I can update the template / data inside a Ractive instance .

I have the following modal window:

```
<div id="modal" intro-outro="fade:100">
    <div id="content">{{>content}}</div>
</div>
```

And **>content** is a ranking template. Imaging that clicking on a player will need to overwrite the ranking with the playerProfile template and it's requested data. Is there another way this could be done aside teardown and then reinitialise the modal window with the playerProfile template ?

**UPDATE**

I forgot to mention that the window will wrap around 20 templates at the moment (which will grow in the future as the game gets more complex). The window I am talking about is the main modal window that shows every template that user triggers, like rankings, mails, reports, tribes, map etc.

Regards.

**WORKAROUND**
Marty's answer is correct but I'd rather not complicate myself and just create new instances of Ractive inside the **#content** div than create different instances of the whole modal window which will be shown on init and hidden on teardown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just have two states (as opposed to open-ended dynamism), you can block them conditionally:

```
<div id="modal" intro-outro="fade:100">
    <div id="content">
        {{^selected}}{{>partial1}}{{/}}
        {{#selected}}{{>partial2}}{{/}}
    </div>
</div>
```

You can augment the data model after initial render. Supposed you had a player click handler:

```
ractive.on('playerSelected', function(e){
    //however your data works...
    $.get('/player?id=' + e.context.id, function(data){
        ractive.set(e.keypath + '.player', data.player)
        ractive.set(e.keypath + '.selected', true)
    })
})
```

If you need a more dynamic approach, you can use a component to set the partial dynamically. Here's an example (http://jsfiddle.net/9Vja5/2/) of how you can do it in 4.0 (4.1 will offer a few improvements in this area). Use a component in the main template:

```
<div>
    {{#reset}}
    <dynamicPartial partial='{{partial}}'/>
    {{/}}
</div>
```

Then set the template to the supplied partial in the component `beforeInit`:

```
Ractive.components.dynamicPartial = Ractive.extend({
    beforeInit: function(o){
        o.template = '{{>' + o.data.partial + '}}'
    }
})
```

The partials need to either be defined globally, or on the dynamic component.

I'm using a partial because that's what you had in your question. You could set the template directly if you had a list of which template to assign. Or you could also set the template to a component via `'<' + component + '/>'`.

The reset is a bit of a hack to force Ractive to re-render the component:

```
r.observe('partial', function(){
    r.set('reset', false)
    r.set('reset', true)
})
```

Otherwise it would just change the data in same component instance, which wouldn't get it to recreate and assign a new template.

Comment: @martydpx I read your answer and it fits my needs, the problem is that ranking is not the only template the window will wrap. There are like 20 other templates that could have the same behaviour since it's a game that I'm talking about. I'm really sorry I didn't specify, I'll update the question right away.

Comment: @edduvs added a dynamic partial example to give you some ideas

Comment: It's okay, rather than complicating myself with this, I'll just wait untill RactiveJS will be developed further in this area , and I'll just get rid of the window ractive instance, and insert it in the dom when page loads, then just make new instances of the templates inside the content div so the window doesn't need to teardown then init again.